# Q: Encoded URL not working when ran from Microsoft Test Manager

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests, microsoft-test-manager

I am new to Microsoft Test Manager, we have Coded UI Automation which we have integrated with Microsoft Test Manager.
We have our Application URL that contains %2B and when i run it in my local the application launch successfully in IE 11 but when i run it from Microsoft Test Manager it launch the URL but it Converts %2B to + in Agent system.

Agent configuration: Windows Server 2008. 
My Local: Windows 10

Can anybody please me about the above issue?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.